# How can I change more images thumbnail image placement on product page?

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images, product-view, page-layouts

I want to show more views images thumbnail in the left of the main image.

[image]

Anyone please suggest me how can I do that.

Answer (score 1):

it's managed by `app/design/frontend/theme-folder/theme/etc/view.xml`

```
<vars module="Magento_Catalog">
    <var name="gallery">
    <var name="navdir">vertical</var> <!-- Sliding direction of thumbnails (horizontal/vertical) -->
    </var>
</vars>
```